# Java for every odd multiply of 90

Tags: java

I need to create a program which prints something for every odd multiply of 90 so for example 
90 - text
180 - nothing happens
270 - text
360 - nothing happens
etc.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try an if statement. And actually putting effort into writing your own code, before asking for help.

Comment: Step 1 - Open an IDE. Step 2 - Create a class. Step 3 - Write some code in the class. Step 4 - Compile. Repeat Steps 3 and 4 until expected result comes out.

Comment: @Compass I think you should [be more explicit in Step 2](https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4003/4633000725_8817dcedb9_z.jpg).

Comment: we're not here to do your job but to try to help you with the issues you're facing. If you're looking for coders, check http://www.getacoder.com/

Comment: 270 will print some text and 360 wont print anything

Comment: @ElliotFrisch That'll cost me my hourly working rate, sir. :P

Comment: just think about it for 2 minutes, its not hard to configure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your basic structure here should be pretty simple - just use a multiplier and an if statement with a modulus operator.

For example (pseudo-code - check a tutorial if you can't implement this idea):

```
int multiplier=1;
int maxMultiplier = 10;
int value = 0;

while (multiplier < maxMultiplier) {
  value = 90 * multiplier;
  if (multiplier % 2 == 0) {
    // print something;
    }
  multiplier++;
}
```

Comment: Please don't do people's homework for them. We really should not be encouraging "give me the code"/zero-effort questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is to print the multiples of 180.

```
for(int i = 180; i < max; i += 180)
    System.out.println(i);
```

I assume this is homework, but there is no point copying someone's answer unless you can explain it.  This is for you education purposes.  (And your marker will be able to pick up code you probably didn't write yourself)